# Why am I getting ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError while displaying data in a datatable (even though the query runs fine in pgadmin) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables, model

[image]

I have 2 tables `facilities` and `amount_availables` as shown above.

These are the first few lines of my models which are important to this issue:

```rb
class AmountAvailable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sequence_number
  belongs_to :facility

  validates :facility, :presence => true
  validates_uniqueness_of :facility_id, scope: [:sequence_number_id], :message => "The Entry must contain a unique record"
  validates :amount_available, numericality: { other_than: 0 }
  validates_format_of :amount_available, :with => /\A[-]*[0-9]+\.[0-9]*{2}\z/, :message => "must contain only digits"

  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    :facility_id => ""
  }

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr, options={})
    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
  end

  before_save { last_updated_by.upcase! }
```

```
class Facility < ApplicationRecord

  before_save { facility.upcase! }
  before_save { financial_institution.upcase! }

  audited
end
```

I am trying to fetch all `AmountAvailable` records and display them in a datatable.

This is my datatable class:

```rb
class SearchAmountAvailableDatatable < Datatable

  SORTABLE_COLUMNS = %w(entity facility financial_institution)

  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
    @tabular = Tabular.new(view.params)
    @search_string = []
  end  

  def data

    #if a search paramater has no selections from the UI, then remove that field from the filter condition
    if !$search_financial_institution.blank? && !$search_facility.blank? && !$search_entity.blank?
      result_set = AmountAvailable.joins(:sequence_number, :facility).where("sequence_numbers.as_of_date >= ? and sequence_numbers.as_of_date <= ? and facilities.entity in (?) and facilities.facility in (?) and facilities.financial_institution in (?)", $search_start_date, $search_end_date, $search_entity, $search_facility, $search_financial_institution).select(:entity, :facility, :financial_institution, :amount_available, :comments, :last_updated_on, :last_updated_by).order('last_updated_on desc') 
    elsif !$search_facility.blank? && !$search_entity.blank?
      result_set = AmountAvailable.joins(:sequence_number, :facility).where("sequence_numbers.as_of_date >= ? and sequence_numbers.as_of_date <= ? and facilities.entity in (?) and facilities.facility in (?)", $search_start_date, $search_end_date, $search_entity, $search_facility).select(:entity, :facility, :financial_institution, :amount_available, :comments, :last_updated_on, :last_updated_by).order('last_updated_on desc') 
    elsif !$search_entity.blank?
      result_set = AmountAvailable.joins(:sequence_number, :facility).where("sequence_numbers.as_of_date >= ? and sequence_numbers.as_of_date <= ? and facilities.entity in (?) ", $search_start_date, $search_end_date, $search_entity).select(:entity, :facility, :financial_institution, :amount_available, :comments, :last_updated_on, :last_updated_by).order('last_updated_on desc') 
    else
      result_set = AmountAvailable.joins(:sequence_number, :facility).where("sequence_numbers.as_of_date >= ? and sequence_numbers.as_of_date <= ?", $search_start_date, $search_end_date).select(:entity, :facility, :financial_institution, :amount_available, :comments, :last_updated_on, :last_updated_by).order('last_updated_on desc') 
    end

    return result_set
  end
```

As you can see above the `data` method returns the data to be displayed in my datatable. Here it does some filtering based on a few input values selected by the user.

If the user does not select any values in the UI, then the `else` block in above code returns all data without any filters.

This is controller class:

```rb
class SearchAmountAvailableController < ApplicationController

  def init
  end

  def run_search
    logger.info "SearchAmountAvailableController run_search"

    $search_start_date = params[:search_start_date]
    $search_end_date = params[:search_end_date]
    $search_entity = params[:search_entity]
    $search_facility = params[:search_facility]
    $search_financial_institution = params[:search_financial_institution]

    data_table = SearchAmountAvailableDatatable.new(view_context)     
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json do
        render json: {
          "pageLength"      => data_table.page_length,
          "recordsTotal"    => data_table.records_total,
          "recordsFiltered" => data_table.records_filtered,
          "data"            => data_table.run_data
        }
      end
    end    
    render :partial => "search/aa/run_search.js.erb"
  end

  def index
    logger.info "SearchAmountAvailableController index"

    data_table = SearchAmountAvailableDatatable.new(view_context)     
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json do
        render json: {           # This is line # 37 which throws the error
          "pageLength"      => data_table.page_length,
          "recordsTotal"    => data_table.records_total,
          "recordsFiltered" => data_table.records_filtered,
          "data"            => data_table.data
        }
      end
    end      
  end
```

**The Issue**

When applying filters on Amount Available, I don't get any issues. But when no filters are applied, I see an error:

```rb
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "entity", "facility", "financial_institution", "amount_availables"."amount_available", "amount_availables"."comments", "amount_availables"."last_updated_on", "amount_availables"."last_updated_by" FROM "amount_availables" INNER JOIN "sequence_numbers" ON "sequence_numbers"."sequence_number" = "amount_availables"."sequence_number_id" INNER JOIN "facilities" ON "facilities"."id" = "amount_availables"."facility_id" WHERE (sequence_numbers.as_of_date >= '10/01/2019' and sequence_numbers.as_of_date <= '11/21/2019') ORDER BY last_updated_on desc
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 51ms (ActiveRecord: 15.7ms)



ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (missing attribute: facility_id):

app/controllers/search_amount_available_controller.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in index'
app/controllers/search_amount_available_controller.rb:34:in `index'
```

But when I run the above query in pgadmin, I don't get any errors and I get a few records returned.

This is the query that runs when I add a filter (`division = 'TRS'`):

```rb
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "entity", "facility", "financial_institution", "amount_availables"."amount_available", "amount_availables"."comments", "amount_availables"."last_updated_on", "amount_availables"."last_updated_by" FROM "amount_availables" INNER JOIN "sequence_numbers" ON "sequence_numbers"."sequence_number" = "amount_availables"."sequence_number_id" INNER JOIN "facilities" ON "facilities"."id" = "amount_availables"."facility_id" WHERE (sequence_numbers.as_of_date >= '10/01/2019' and sequence_numbers.as_of_date <= '11/21/2019' and facilities.entity in ('TRS') ) ORDER BY last_updated_on desc
```

In the above case, I do not get the missing attribute error at all!

Why am I getting this error (only when I don't add any filter)?

Comment: I'm not answering but doing suggestion instead of your if/elsif/... and define your query each time, why not be DRY : if ... specific_query = ... additionnal_params = ... elsif ... specific_query = ... additionnal_params = ... end result_set = AmountAvailable.joins(...).where("sequence_numbers.as_of_date >= ? and sequence_numbers.as_of_date <= ? #{specific_query}", $search_start_date, $search_end_date, additionnal_params).select(...).order(...) It would help a lot to read and see the differences

Comment: @XavM - Thanks much for your suggestion. Very valid/useful point. I'll definitely implement your suggestion.